# Completely in the dark about JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

I've been reading some JSON tutorials and the structure and syntax makes sense to me.. but I am trying to do a project that requires me to do a GET, and it seems to be implying that I can do that with JSON.

I've read that JSON and AJAX can be compared pretty well, so I would assume that this is possible. If I could be directed towards some reading about how to use JSON in this manner, or have it explained, I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Edit: Please reopen this... The fact that it was closed in the first place is appalling. There was a perfectly legitimate discussion going. And not ONE of the people who closed it bothered adding anything.

Comment: JSON is a Javascript Object and AJAX is a methodology using Javascript to make asynchronous web requests. Not sure how they intertwine for you here. You typically use JSON in your code to make an AJAX call... I could write a jQuery call as an example should you wish.

Comment: @phpisuber01 JSON is not a javascript object. It's javascript object notation.

Comment: JSON is basically turning an object into a string. AJAX is basically sending and receiving things to/from the server without exiting the current page.

Comment: JQuery is another thing I am confused about. Is it natively supported or is their some installation process?

Comment: @Joshua - jQuery is a library, that let you to do more stuff with less code. It is not natively supported. For example, normally you would do `document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "bar"`, but with jQuery, `$("#foo").html("bar")`.

Comment: @phpisuber01: JSON is a data formt, like XML. A JavaScript object is a data type in JavaScript. They are only somewhat related because the JSON syntax is similar to the object literal syntax in JS.

Comment: If you're really trying to thoroughly grok JSON, I recommend going directory to the source: http://www.json.org/ Douglas Crockford's description there is very thorough, with pretty pictures, and stuff

Comment: one thing is sure @Joshua that JSON is preferred over XML because JSON is usually smaller in size! you can save like 20%~30% bandwidth if you transfer data using JSON!
May be in application specific scenarios you can't replace XML sometimes.. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are you're trying to *get JSON* not *get with JSON*. JSON is just the 'format' (notation) of the response, not the method of retrieval.

You tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) but not [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) (although you mention `get` and `AJAX` which is usually synonymous to jQuery's [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) AJAX call.) Bbecause it's a lot simpler than plain-jane JavaScript and to stick with brevity, the following is an example of retrieving JSON data using [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Let's assume that there is a method on the server that returns JSON data (found at `/my/service.json`) something to the effect of the following:

```
{
  "first_name": "Brad",
  "last_name": "Christie"
}
```

<sup>note: this is basically outputting something similar to an Object-Oriented language's "Account" class with two properties: `first_name` & `last_name` but *notated* in JSON to other languages (your AJAX query) can understand the information)</sup>

You can use AJAX to retrieve this like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $getJSON('/my/service.json'.function(data){
      alert(data.first_name + ' ' + data.last_name); // shows "Brad Christie"
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

Follow-up: I see you have questions in c++ so let's try to provide a working example. I'll assume you've worked with `struct`, so let's say you have the following:

```
struct stockitem {
  int itemid;
  float price;
  string description; // :grin: this example #include <string> ;-)
} mystock;

mystock.itemid = 21;
mystock.price = 20.12;
mystock.description = "This Year";
```

If you were going to send this information off to something, you could serialize it a lot of different ways. One of those ways is to use JSON (which would probably look like this):

```
{
  "itemid":21,
  "price":20.12,
  "description":"This Year"
}
```

Now, the other end really isn't going to know that it's a struct vs. a class or some other data type, but in javascript it'll become a basic object with similar functionality and access:

```
var mystock = /*the above JSON */;
alert(mystock + '. ' + mystock.description + ' for $' + mystock.price.toFixed(2));
// above outputs: 21. This Year for $20.12
```

And, above all, you just used JSON to transfer (notarize) the original struct.

Comment: This is very helpful. I was confused about whether or not JSON was just a format or if it had functionality of it's own.

Comment: JSON is simply the "language" information is stored in. It's simply "i have this information and JSON is how I need to store it so the next person can read it as I intended".

Comment: @BradChristie - More straightforward: JSON is just putting doublequotes around the object and making it a string.

Comment: @Joshua: You can compare JSON with XML, CSV, YAML, etc. They all are ways to represent data and there are libraries to convert these formats into native data types. People sometimes mistakenly refer to JS *object literals* as JSON, but these are really two pair of shoes.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer. I wasn't expecting you to look at my history and put it in terms I was familiar with. Pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that JSON data is normally transmitted in the payload of the HTTP request. Get requests don't have bodies, therefore no JSON (being transmitted TO the server). However, you can receive JSON data via a GET request.

POST doesn't have this limitation because data is sent in the payload of the request.

Comment: How would one queue a GET request using JSON?

Comment: JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. It isn't a mechanism or an action. JSON is how objects are formatted as text. You can queue up an AJAX request that recieves JSON-formatted data.

Comment: Couldn't you put JSON in the query string of a GET request, with escaping as appropriate? (I'm not saying it's a _good_ idea, just that it's possible.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes you can URL-encode your JSON-encoded object and place it in the query-string. Keep in mind most URLs are restricted to 255 characters so you are very limited to how much data you can transmit.